# Export as "HTML + ToC" not working on my Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter Notebook file that has a numbered table of contents. However, when I wanted to export is as html. The HTML option and the HTML + ToC option showed exactly the same output. No one included my numbered headings (just regular headings but no numbers, say 1.2, 2.2.3, etc.). Any ideas? Did I use a wrong method to export? I used the embedded "Download as" button.

[image]